# UIBarButtonItem event handling not working

Tags: objective-c

I'm try to catch the event of back button and trigger the `didClickBarButtonnLeft:` method.

The following code does not work:

```
[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTarget:self];
[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setAction:@selector(didClickBarButtonnLeft:)];
```

But this it does:

```
UIBarButtonItem* barButtonLeft;
 barButtonLeft = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:SIDE_VIEW_BAR_BUTTON]
                                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                    target:self
                                                    action:@selector(didClickBarButtonnLeft:)];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonLeft;

    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

The point is I don't want to replace the default back button icon. Both scripts are inside of `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` method.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a couple things that could help. First, the best way to access the back button on the navigationItem is to say:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem
```

Try using that instead of `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` and see if anything changes.

Secondly, if all you want to do is detect when the view controller is being removed from the navigation stack, you can override `viewWillDisappear:` and implement it like the following:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController)
    {
        // call your back button pressed method
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a event handler.

Comment: It will still work the same way. viewWillDisappear: is called when your view controller is moving off the screen. From the docs: isMovingFromParentViewController "Returns a Boolean value that indicates that the view controller is in the process of being removed from its parent." Thus, the same effect is achieved.

Comment: Unless, of course, you are trying to override what the back button is doing. In that case, either try option 1 I mentioned or just hide the back button and create a new bar button item that looks like the back button.